# Gatwick Easyjet North Terminal machine drop - Tolerated amount of weight exceeding upper limit for hold luggage

Tags: air-travel, legal, luggage, check-in

Recently, I was booked on a flight on EasyJet between two European capitals. I had a ticket allowing me for one bag of max 20 kg. However, when my bag was weighted at the check-in counter, it weighted 21.9 kg but (to my surprise) the machine at the counter accept it.

So my question: is there a "tolerated" amount of weight exceed (for example max + 1kg above the upper limit) for the machines in Gatwick Easyjet North Terminal ?

Comment: Obviously there is, but they arent going to advertise what it is, now are they? :)  And any figure the is posted by other people is liable to change with no notice, as EasyJet only have an obligation up to the stated allowance on the ticket.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. As @Moo says, no EasyJet employee is going to admit that the allowance is really 22kg, and anybody else would just be guessing.

Comment: Voting to leave open, this is well answerable. E.g. I asked Ryanair staff at HHN who were happy to tell me that .9kg above the limit was fine before I proceeded to re-pack my 5kg of overweight.

Comment: If there was an official 'tolerance' above the maximum limit, that would be the maximum limit. If it was not an official 'tolerance' then you might find that on your particular flight they decided to apply the limit strictly. So this isn't going to have an accurate answer.

Comment: Perfectly good question. Just because it can change in the future doesn't mean it's not useful now.

Comment: The tolerance is probably based on the scale's actual tolerance -- the amount that the scale is expected to be off by. For example, if the scale is calibrated to +/-2kg, they'll likely allow 2kg over. That said, the scale could be at the high end of its calibration, so not a good idea to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, up to 1kg (Europe) over the officially stated limit was *always* acceptable. This included a wide range of airlines, both mainstream and nickel-and-dime ones like RyanAir, WizzAir and AirAsia. No experience with Spirit though.

Up to 2kg was *sometimes* acceptable depending on unknown factors such as the mood of the check in counter person, and your frequent miler status. Never experienced acceptance of over 2kg in person check-in, however the machines itself might be programmed to higher tolerance (and possibly have damaged scales).